# Hiding World of Warcraft UI Elements with Lua

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft-modding

I'm tyring to make a very simple WoW addon that hides the gryphons on either side of the main menu bar and hides the micro buttons in the lower right. The addon has one Lua script, main.lua:

```
-- main.lua
MainMenuBarArtFrame.LeftEndCap:Hide()
MainMenuBarArtFrame.RightEndCap:Hide()
MicroButtonAndBagsBar:Hide()
CharacterMicroButton:Hide()
SpellbookMicroButton:Hide()
TalentMicroButton:Hide()
AchievementMicroButton:Hide()
QuestLogMicroButton:Hide()
GuildMicroButton:Hide()
LFDMicroButton:Hide()
CollectionsMicroButton:Hide()
StoreMicroButton:Hide()
EJMicroButton:Hide()
MainMenuMicroButton:Hide()
```

This works perfectly, except the micro button for the shop will not go away. In game, if I enter `/run StoreMicroButton:Hide()` into the chat, the button will be hidden. Why will the script not hide this element? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `TalentMicroButton:Hide()A` (line break) `chievementMicroButton:Hide()` - is this typo in the file?

Comment: @trollingchar Oh, no, it’s not. I just messed up when typing out the question. Thank you for catching that!